# Persuading POSTGRES to use a sensible INDEX

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have a table with field defined as

```
eventTime        TIMESTAMP
```

The field is indexed.

Most of the queries against this table involve querying data for one particular day, so `WHERE` clauses often contain something like this...

```
WHERE date_trunc('day',eventTime) = '2022-Jun-01'
```

This takes ages (several seconds) to execute because it doesn't use the index (because `date_trunc()` is too complex a function).

If I use this clause instead the index gets used, and the operation take a few milliseconds.

```
WHERE eventTime <= '2022-Jun-01 23:59:59' and eventTime >= '2022-Jun-01 00:00:00'
```

Is there anyway to achieve the convenience of the first example, with the execution time of the second. (basically I'm lazy and don't like typing!)

Comment: Create an index on the expression. Note that your second example is better written as `where eventtime >= '2022-06-01' and eventtime < '2022-06-02'`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  - that seems to work!